# Is there a R function that would help me merging two dataframe?

Tags: r

I have columns `Name` in list.x and `Name`,`Suburb` in list.y. I am willing to join them list.x and list.y. The problem is, `Name` in list.x is,

1. `Name` in list.x separated by `!` whereas in list.y separated by `,`
2. `Name` in list.x First name then last na,e `!` whereas in list.y Last name then First name.

```
list.x = data.frame(
         Name = c("John!Citizen","Dipayan!Banerjee","Smith!Langley!White"))

list.y = data.frame(
Name = c("White,Smith,Langley","Citizen,John","Banerjee,Dipayan"),
Suburb = c("Langley","Mars","Here"))
```

I want to match `x.list` with `y.list` by `Name` and map the `Suburb`.

Comment: Why not replace needed characters with `sub` and then run `merge`?

Comment: Sorry, `merge` would also work, actually I would be using `Join` function to map.

Comment: Please show your expected output for the data shared.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to reverse and sub your names, that pretty easy, but lets condense it to a single function to save you some time. Here it puts the last name first and then adds the other names.

```
revcollapse <- function(x) { paste(c(x[length(x)],x[-length(x)]), collapse=",") }
```

then you can fix the `list.x` `Name` variable

```
list.x$Name <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(list.x$Name, split="[!]"), revcollapse))
```

Now you can merge.

```
new.list <- merge(list.x, list.y, by="Name")
```

you'll probably want to mess with `all.x` and `all.y` in the `merge` call.

Edited to fix "Smith!Langley!White" issue in comments.

Comment: Thanks you @pdb for the solution. It worked. However, stretching the solution. Instead of reversing the strings, can I sort it? For example "John Citizen" will be "Citizen John" in both list.x and list.y

Comment: Also with your initial solution, it works fine when there is two words in the name, with "Smith!Langley!White" it reverse operation is not working.

Comment: fair regarding that odd case. For the new question, I'd open a new question. But I'd search for how to order a data frame first, there should be plenty of issues for you.